# Storing large amount of text / mySQL row size limit

Tags: mysql

I am doing a bit of web scraping (following robot.txt guidelines).

My goal is to standardize (normalize?) the data into numbers that can fit easily into columns.  I believe I have accomplished this.  However I am not certain that I've gathered all the relevant data from the source code.  As such, I am planning on ALSO storing some of the raw data (similar to the source code but cleaned up a bit).

This cleaned-up data is around 30,000 - 40,000 characters per page.  As I understand, the max character limit is approx 65,000 characters for TEXT values.  However, I also read that there is a MAX BYTE limit per row of approx 65,000 bytes.  And it says UTF stores characters at 3 bytes per characters.  So is there a way to store this much text in an SQL table?

Comment: You're interpreting wrong. A text/blob field DOES require some space in the table's 64k-per-row limit, but only a few bytes to store the size of the text, which is stored elsewhere. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense.  The table only stores the location (pointer) of the actual text data.  Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't quite say pointer. that goes into the record metadata, but what does count against the row limit is the bytes required to store the number representing the SIZE of the text in that field. e.g. mediumtext has a 24bit length limit, so a medium text field needs 3 bytes of table space. with a 64k max, you could only have 21,845 mediumtext fields in your table.

Comment: Don't you mean only 21,845 medium text fields in a row?  Table sizes can be massive.

Comment: It's a lot fewer than that (per row).  Apparently, from some [old comments I wrote and now don't remember writing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45862/11651) something like 43 bytes are consumed per blob column (which includes `TEXT`)... so the limit is around 186 columns.  The documentation has been vague and/or incorrect for quite some time on this topic.  Using the `Barracuda` file format, iirc, the docs do mention a 20 byte pointer to off-page storage.

Comment: ...but a `LONGTEXT` column can hold 2^32-1 bytes of data.